# Course of action when Delphi detects recoverable files?

Tags: delphi, ide, file-recovery, delphi-10.2-tokyo

My Delphi Tokyo 10.2.1 IDE just crashed. On restart I get the prompt:

[image]

> RAD Studio has recovered the following files. Save the ones you wish to keep.

A file compare shows that at that moment the file in `__recovery` is indeed the latest version, but **nothing has been recovered yet**
(Note: The specific file was not re-opened in the IDE, because the crash prevented the IDE from registering that as an open file. The project that this file is part of was not even the current one in the project group, for that same reason).

The dialog only has a *Close* button. I can select that file or not. I started testing several variations.

Regardless of whether I select it, after clicking *Close*, Delphi asks *Discard remaining recovered files?*.

- If I then choose No, nothing changes. The file is not recovered, the contents of `__recovery` remain unchanged
- I wanted to test this also when I choose Yes, but no amount of copying the old source file plus `__recovery` folder now triggers the IDE warning again. I can not test further variations. The IDE now keeps clearing out the `__recovery` folder.

This is a bit of a mess. Does recovery not work? Are the dialog texts so unclear?

I would expect the following behavior from such a dialog:

- It presents me with the detected files. The text says: *RAD Studio has* **discovered** *the following files.* **Select** *the ones you wish to keep*.
- The user must select the files he wants recovered.
- If any unrecovered files remain the *Discard remaining recovered files* message comes up.

**Does anyone know what (f)actually happens? What am I supposed to do (select/answer) here?**
I could not find the answer online.

Because right now I am left with a not recovered file and an empty `__recovery` folder. Luckily I made backups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double click the list item to open it in the editor, but as the original file with unsaved changes, i.e. the same state it was at the point of the auto save.